# Why won't Korir offer me work (retrieving the Helm of Winterhold)?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am playing Skyrim SE on Windows Steam. I have completed the Companions questline but have not started the civil war.

In order to become [Thane of Winterhold](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thane_of_Winterhold) I need to ask [Korir](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Korir) for work and then complete the quest he gives me (to [retrieve the Helm of Winterhold from a random location](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dungeon_Delving_(Jarl_-_Caves))). But when I talk to him, he never offers me the job.

- I am level 47
- Disposition: *(pending)*
- getStage Favor158: 200 (empty)
- getStage Favor257: 200 (empty)

How can I fix this? (Console commands welcome)

**Things I've tried (without success):**

- Setting the stage of Favor158 to 0

**Similar questions (with no answers):**

- https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/2896604-trying-to-become-thane-of-winterhold/
- https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/65440015
- Other questions relate to getting the "Thane" quest after completing the "Helm" quest, but I can't even get the "Helm" quest

Comment: if someone can confirm the name of the quest as it appears in the game I can check that I don't already have it, thanks

Comment: It's a Miscellaneous (i.e, unnamed) quest.

Answer (score 5):

The [discussion page for this quest on UESP](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Thane_of_Winterhold) discusses this issue. It seems to be related to the Hearthfire addon.

> If you have Hearthfire installed and have any one of the of "Build your own Home quests" started but not completed, you will not be allowed to accept any Thane quests from any other Thanes in any other holds. Even though I had already become a Thane in Hjaalmarch, I had not yet visited the homestead property, nor began construction on the house. Upon visiting the property and building the foundation, the quest completed. I immediately returned to Winterhold and was able to begin and instantly finish this quest.

So if you have Hearthfire installed, try to visit your property and build the foundation. The quest should complete and you'll be able to take "Become Thane of X" quests.

Answer (score 3):

Becoming Thane of Winterhold is not exclusive to Korir.  Additionally, the Helm quest is a *technically* radiant quest and doesn't have easily accessible quest triggers.

To ensure all conditions are met to get Korir to talk business, ensure the following are all true:

1. It is during Korir's normal court hours.  Target 10AM-1PM and you're probably good.
2. Korir is not under attack
3. You did not tell Korir "no" if he offered you the task previously.

If you shut Korir down on his request the first time, or broke dialog before he could offer it, it's possible his dialog bugged and he considers it a rejection of the task.   If so, you can either reload a previous save before you met him, or win the war for the Empire.

If the Empire wins Winterhold, via war or just trade in Season Unending, they seat Kraldar as Jarl.  Kraldar will give you the Thane quest of just helping people in the hold, instead of sending you to get the Helm first.

Answer (score -1):

Finish the Bounty quest first that you can get from the Inn owner.. Interestingly enough, upon getting the Thane quest, I thought I'd be sent off to Yngol Burrow but to Pride of Tel Vos instead